# Is there an implementation of ScheduledFuture?

Tags: java

I'm writing a method that looks like this:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService executor;

public ScheduledFuture<?> doSomething() {
  if (someConditionIsMet()) {
    return executor.schedule(() -> doSomethingInternal(), delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  }
  return ?;
}
```

Basically, I want something like `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null)`, but that returns an instance of a class that implements `ScheduledFuture`.

Is there an existing class like this?

Comment: What about returning `Optional` instead?

Comment: It's an option, but it would needlessly complicate code

Comment: What would you expect the create future to look like? What would be its delay? Would it be cancelled? `CompletableFuture.completedFuture` gives you just that, a (succesfully) completed future. What would a `ScheduledFuture.create` be able to reasonably give you?

Comment: It can be a result bearing future just like `CompletableFuture.completedFuture`. Its delay can be 0. It wouldn't be canceled.

Comment: Be aware that asking us to find / recommend a library is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a class like this in the standard library, or Guava, Apache Commons, or any other popular libraries?

That question is off-topic.

But if you can't find an existing library that provides this functionality, it is simple to write the class yourself.  Most of the methods are trivial.  Something like this should do:

```
public class CompletedScheduledFuture<T> implements ScheduledFuture<T> {
    private T value;

    public CompletedScheduledFuture(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T get() { return value; }
    public T get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) { return value; }
    public boolean cancel() { return false; }
    public boolean isDone() { return true; }
    public boolean isCancelled() { return false; }
    public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) { return 0; }

    public int compareTo(Delayed other) {
        Long.compare(getDelay(NANOSECONDS), 
                     other.getDelay(NANOSECONDS));
    }
}
```

---

> Yes, I just don't like to reinvent the wheel and even more so to do it in every new project.

I would be reluctant to make my applications depend on a 3rd-party library for something as simple / easy to implement as this.

But, if you really need this class in lots of projects, you can create a library project that you can reuse.

Comment: Yes, I just don't like to reinvent the wheel and even more so to do it in every new project.

Comment: So roll it into your own utility library and you'll have it for all of your projects